# How to Read JSON String using plain Java Code (without using any Jar files)

Tags: java, json

In Java there is lot of way to read JSON String, but what I am looking for is without using any Jar File, is there any way to read JSON plain String using core Java Functions or written scripts.

For Example, A method which returns value of the key sent with two parameter
1 - JSON String
2 - Key or JSON Locator (e.g, accountname.id) which we need to find and return value

I have written one code which can approaches my question but not completely

```
public static String GetJSONValue(String JSONString, String Field)
{
       return JSONString.substring(JSONString.indexOf(Field), JSONString.indexOf("\n", JSONString.indexOf(Field))).replace(Field+"\": \"", "").replace("\"", "").replace(",","");   
}
```

Above code has lots of limitations...plus it should cover array of JSON and support JSON locators?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel, when there are plenty good options to choose from?

Comment: You will need to implement a JSON parser yourself. Do you really have that much time?

Comment: Modified the question, JSON is now in trend...what my approach is when you are creating application such as using JFrame instead of adding JAR file and eating memory its better if you have your own code to read JSON String. Basically I want to avoid adding Jar files to a Java Project.

Comment: XY problem. Java's strength is in its vast ecosystem. Have a look into gradle and maven. It's very easy to include an existing module into your application.

Comment: Might I ask why you are against "using a Jar File"?
As rustyx mentioned, the power of modern languages (e.g. Java) is in all the stuff that is available to you to make your life easier and more productive...
One way or another, you will be "adding the code", and memory is much much cheaper than your time in this day and age.

Answer (score 1):

If you are absolutely unshakably determined to parse the JSON without using a jar library, you will need to write a parser of some sort. This can be alot of work. There are however solutions available online in the form of parsers (e.g. Antlr or javacc and more).
Most, but not all, parsers require Jar libraries to be distributed with your application. Javacc is one that does not.

javacc is a code generator (i.e. it generates java code) that is compiled (from source files) into your application. Javacc takes a grammar file and generates the corresponding java code from that grammar file. You then compile your application along with the generated java files in the normal way.

You can get javacc here (it downloads jar files, but these do not form part of your application) and can be configured to run from the command line or as a plugin in your IDE:

https://javacc.org/

some JSON grammars can be found here:

https://github.com/RobertFischer/json-parser/tree/master/src/main/javacc/com/smokejumperit/json/parser

and/or

https://github.com/mwnorman/JSONParser/tree/master/src/org/mwnorman/json

The files you want have extension *.jj (and *.jjt). The second grammar example shows the type of source that is generated.

Comment: @ravi_creed if this answer has helped you, could you please accept the answer (and upvote it)? Thanks.